# How to create center image in div?

Tags: html, css, image, center

i have image with resolution 1000px*1000px,

this my html :

```
<style> 
 .test{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  }
</style>

<div class="test"> <img src="..."/> </div>
<div class="test"> <img src="..."/> </div>
<div class="test"> <img src="..."/> </div>
<div class="test"> <img src="..."/> </div>
```

if original image full body, i want when on div only visible the face.
i do not know how to make it.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use background into DIV instead of IMG and then set position of background

Comment: i think i can't use this way, because it will be slide. so any four < div> < img/> </ div>

Comment: do you have any example of what you tring to do

Comment: i want to only people and umbrella visible [link](http://jsfiddle.net/936bxd41/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE THIS HACK.

1. Let all the `<img>` tag have a `src` value to the same image (e.g. transparent-image.png). Using an image editor, set the image `opacity` to zero, thus making the image completely transparent. This transparent image should be made 1px by 1px in size.
2. Then set an inline style on all the `<img>` tag with `background-image` set to an image of your choice. Understand that the `src` value (transparent-image.png i.e image with `opacity` set to zero) as set on the `<img>` will not obstruct visibility of its own `background-image` as defined in the inline style. This is because the image opacity is set to zero.
3. Lastly, create a css rule on the `<img>` tag and set the `background-position` to `center` vertical and `center` horizontal. For example;

   `.test img { background-position: center center; }`

Below is a template putting together all I have explained.

The HTML

```
<div class="test"> 
    <img src="transparent-image.png" style="background-image:url(image1.jpg)" /> 
</div>
<div class="test"> 
    <img src="transparent-image.png" style="background-image:url(image2.jpg)" /> 
</div>
<div class="test"> 
    <img src="transparent-image.png" style="background-image:url(image3.jpg)" /> 
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.test img {
    background-position: center center; /* you can adjust this with values. Eg 50% 50% */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need me to set up a live example for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let start from this version and then let see where we end up.
This is example with 1000x1000px image centered in background of 400x400px DIV element.
What kind of slide do you wana apply to it?

```css
div{
    background: url('http://curezone.com/upload/Members/New02/nasa1R3107_1000x1000.jpg');
    background-position: center; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div>
 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case you can play with numbers like this (EDITED):

```css
.test{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border:5px solid red;
        position: relative;
        background: url('http://winniecooper.net/flores/pics/snow%20umbrella.jpg');
        background-position: 50% 75%;
        background-size: 1000px 1000px;
        -webkit-transition: background 1s;
        -moz-transition: background 1s;
        -o-transition: background 1s;
        transition: background 1s;
}
.test:hover{
        background-position: 0% 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">  </div>
```

UPDATE :o) 
Based on link you gave I can explaine roughly how it's done (or I would done it). This site has DIV with 500% width split in 5 DIV each 20% width of parent DIV (so full screen width, you will have 4 DIV with 25% width). Each DIV has image inside with 100% width of parent DIV. 
So you will see just one image at the time. Using some script you can change position of master DIV. I would change style property left value of master DIV with transition apply to that DIV that would animate that change into slide.
[image: full screen slider]

Comment: Thanks for reply, my post has i edited, there any 4 < div> , when i click one of the image, image will be slide. that's why, i can not use set image be background.

Comment: I've added CSS background transition as example how you can slide image. Try to use it as starting point becouse I cant figure it up what kind of slide do you want. If you have URL with example that would be usefull.

Comment: full background slide , like this [link](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BigVideoSlideshow/)

Comment: I have updated my answer. You will need to combine JS and CSS to accomplish this. Good practice is to open console and examine part of site you wana implement in yours. There you can pick up some ideas (dont just copy snipets becouse you wont be able to alter solution in way you need it. Rather pick up idea and then try to make simple project from it, When you achive basic funcionality then you can grow further.).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for:

```
.test img {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%; 
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Rewriten, this centers the smaller image inside the container here is an working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEodmB)

Comment: I think he want center oversized image in smaller container without image resizing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but image will be small. no full height on < div>

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

HTML

```
<div class="test"> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/> </div>
```

CSS

```
.test{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #000000;
  }

.test img {
    width:350px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/936bxd41/)

Obviously, this is based on your code and you can adjust the widths as you see fit.

There are plenty of places where you can look more into this as well. [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) has a good article on this.

N.B. This is on the assumption that you only want to horizontally center the image. Let us know if you need it vertically centered as well.